# Facebook api post picture with message as a link on page wall

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to post on a page wall a picture with a message which is actually a link which works as a Link Post similar to the link published by entering "@page_name" inside status box (with the popup story info on mouse over)?
I mean: is it possible to post a photo (or even a video) with a link as the message?

Using "picture" or "thumbnail" parameters on Link Post shows only the small picture.

Comment: You can put any HTTP URL inside the message parameter, Facebook will render it as a clickable link. (But be aware that pre-filling the message parameter when posting to a user's wall is against Platform Policies, the users have to enter the message themselves.)

Comment: Actually I need it on a page wall. Is it against the policies?

Comment: Ok, facebook renders it as a clickable link, but it shows the link as the text: http://something.com. Is it possible to set something like an "<a href="link">text</a>", showing only the text?

Comment: No, that’s not possible.

Comment: Thank you... that's explain why I was not able to find a solution on the web... !